# Restrict GPU memory allocation for jax based tool

Tags: python, jax

I'm trying to run a Bayesian model (https://github.com/cbg-ethz/scDEF) that runs with jax.
The data set I want to process is quite large and the tools seems to keep crashing because it tries to allocate more GPU memory than is available.

I'm running it on a windows PC, with 24GB GPU memory and 516GB RAM available.

cudatoolkit 11.2
cuDNN 8.1
jax 0.3.20
jaxlib 0.3.20

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\username\scdef\fnl_scdef.py", line 146, in <module>
    scd.learn(n_epoch = opt["nrep"])
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\scdef\scdef.py", line 665, in learn
    losses, opt_state = self._optimize(
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\scdef\scdef.py", line 597, in _optimize
    loss, opt_state = update_func(
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\scdef\scdef.py", line 660, in update
    value, gradient = loss_grad(indices, params, key, annealing_parameter)
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\traceback_util.py", line 162, in reraise_with_filtered_traceback
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\api.py", line 604, in cache_miss
    out_flat = xla.xla_call(
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\core.py", line 1959, in bind
    return call_bind(self, fun, *args, **params)
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\core.py", line 1975, in call_bind
    outs = top_trace.process_call(primitive, fun_, tracers, params)
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\core.py", line 701, in process_call
    return primitive.impl(f, *tracers, **params)
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\dispatch.py", line 231, in _xla_call_impl
    compiled_fun = xla_callable(fun, device, backend, name, donated_invars,
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\linear_util.py", line 306, in memoized_fun
    ans = call(fun, *args)
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\dispatch.py", line 367, in _xla_callable_uncached
    keep_unused, *arg_specs).compile().unsafe_call
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\dispatch.py", line 977, in compile
    self._executable = XlaCompiledComputation.from_xla_computation(
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\dispatch.py", line 1098, in from_xla_computation
    compiled = compile_or_get_cached(backend, xla_computation, options,
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\dispatch.py", line 1051, in compile_or_get_cached
    return backend_compile(backend, serialized_computation, compile_options,
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\profiler.py", line 313, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\dispatch.py", line 993, in backend_compile
    return backend.compile(built_c, compile_options=options)
jax._src.traceback_util.UnfilteredStackTrace: jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Out of memory while trying to allocate 34015136256 bytes.

The stack trace below excludes JAX-internal frames.
The preceding is the original exception that occurred, unmodified.

--------------------

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\mpohly\scdef\fnl_scdef.py", line 146, in <module>
    scd.learn(n_epoch = opt["nrep"])
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\scdef\scdef.py", line 665, in learn
    losses, opt_state = self._optimize(
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\scdef\scdef.py", line 597, in _optimize
    loss, opt_state = update_func(
  File "C:\Apps\Miniconda3\envs\scdef\lib\site-packages\scdef\scdef.py", line 660, in update
    value, gradient = loss_grad(indices, params, key, annealing_parameter)
jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Out of memory while trying to allocate 34015136256 bytes.
```

`

Unfortunately, I'm quite new to python (mainly used to R), so any insights would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

I tried reducing the available GPU by specifying:

`import os os.environ["XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_MEM_FRACTION"]="0.70"`

This reduced the GPU usage as observed by taskmanager, but the tool still tries to allocate 31GB of GPU.

Comment: You're definitely going to need to include a [mcve] for this one, likely with randomly generated data replicating the problem at moderate scale.